# Combining two LinQ queries

Tags: c#, linq

I have two linQ queries below and am wondering if there's a way to combine both of them. Essentially I have a list of strings. Then from that list of strings, I want to create a new list of object and order it based on a property of the object. This new list of object, which has been ordered, will then be returned.

```
var dirs = from file in myList
     select new DirectoryInfo(file);

var dirOrdered = from file in dirs
     orderby file.CreationTime ascending
     select file;
```

Is it possible to use one var and have it be done in one query instead of two separate queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var dirs = from file in myList
     let fileInfo = new DirectoryInfo(file)
     orderby fileInfo.CreationTime ascending
     select fileInfo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can try something like this:

```
 var dirs = (from file in myList
               select new DirectoryInfo(file)).OrderBy(x => x.CreationTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer dot notation, you can do this:

```
var dirs = myList.Select(x => new DirectoryInfo(x)).OrderBy(x => x.CreationTime);
```

Comment: That also works, but I can only accept one answer. Thanks for the choices